# How do I open the MacVim GUI?

Tags: user-interface, macvim

I feel like an idiot asking this because I have it working on my iMac at work but can't get it working on my Air.

I have installed the latest version but can only get it to run in a terminal window, not the GUI which I prefer.

Google has plenty of "how to run MacVim in terminal" results but I'm not finding how to do it the other way round and can't remember what I did on the work machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to it in the terminal:

```
:h mvim
```

If you are able to double-click the MacVim.app Application Bundle and launch as per a normal Mac Application, but you are not able to run

```
mvim
```

in a terminal, it seems like mvim may not be in your $PATH.  However, if you are not able to open the MacVim.app at all, then it sounds like a bad compile.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am able to run mvim and open by double-clicking the application icon. I copied mvim to /usr/local/bin as well.

Comment: And if I understand correctly, what you're saying is that when you run mvim command in terminal, you only end up running vim inside the terminal? Is the application in /Applications?

Answer (score 0):

`mvim -g` should open a GUI window, if that's possible. (It might not be if something is wonky with your bootstrap namespaces, which is where `reattach-to-user-namespace` comes in handy.)

`mvim` decides whether or not to call `vim` with `-g` or not based on whether there's a non-empty `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable. If that variable has content, then it assumes you're ssh'd into a server, and the GUI window wouldn't do you any good, so it doesn't provide the `-g` argument.

You can preemptively pass `-g` yourself, and then `mvim`'s antics won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I folowed your guide, but ran into a problem in vi, after installation the statusbar was only visible in the help window of macvim.

I found a solution in the official documentation;
https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#vim-issues

I had to add the following to my .vimrc

```
set laststatus=2
```